# I get this error " Error in log2(exprs(gset)) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Tags: r, runtime-error

The code is this:

```
gset <- ReadAffy()

pData(gset)

b1<-log2(exprs(gset))

boxplot(b1, col = 2:4)

str(exprs(gset))
List of 1
 $ : symbol gset
```

At the third line, I get this error"Error in log2(exprs(gset)): non-numeric argument to mathematical function".

I used the same code and the same data a few days ago without any problem but now I don't know what's wrong. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: `expres(gset)` has to be numeric in order to apply `log2()` function. What does it return when you write `class(exprs(gset))`?

Comment: It's going to be almost impossible to debug this without a reproducible example (which is hard because Affymetrix data sets are big). `str(exprs(gset))` would be useful.

Comment: It returns list. I used it last week and I had no problem. I don't understand what has changed.

Comment: We don't know what has changed either, but it's guaranteed that **something** has changed - either your data, or these aren't **exactly** the same commands, or (less likely) you've updated the package and it doesn't work identically.  Can you please *edit your question* to include the results of `str(exprs(gset))` ?

Comment: make sure you're starting in a clean R session (no unnecessary packages loaded etc.)

Comment: @shapol46 Put additional information in your question (not in comments), i.e. **edit your question!** Make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Actually, I have loaded many unnecessary packages. I open a new session and let you know. The commands are the same. The result of 
 `str(exprs(gset))`   is also the same error. I'll add it.

Comment: I wrote an answer to my question but it isn't here. The problem was due to unnecessary packages but I don't know which one because I had loaded many. Thank you very much, @ Ben Bolker

Answer (score 0):

In line with the idea of conflicting packages highlighted above, a possible explanation can come from the fact that the *exprs* function in the **dplyr** package masks the *exprs* function in the **Biobase** package since both of functions have the same name in both packages.

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/109128/#109719

I have solved the problem in my case by placing  **exprs=Biobase::exprs** at the top of my script.